# Overlay split action bar and make background color semi transparent

Tags: android, facebook, android-actionbar, overlay, transparency

I want to overlay the split action bar and make the background semi transparent, just like facebook.

[image: facebook]

Any iteas please. I tried

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 0)));
```

but it is overlaying the top bar and not the bottom.

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> getActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(yourresource)

I hope it helps !